# Laravel valet linked php error

Tags: laravel-valet

I got an error.

```
$ valet install

[DomainException]                
Unable to determine linked PHP.  

install
```

'which' command returns:

```
$ which php
/usr/local/Cellar/php70/7.0.6/bin/php
```

Comment: Did you used "composer global require laravel/valet"

Comment: Yes I did. Valet is working correctly as in it is showing the lists and version command.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Homebrew creates (or attempts to create) symlinks in `/usr/local/bin`.

Start by running the following to attempt to create a link.

```
brew link php70
```

It'll give you information as to whether or not it was successful. Occasionally permissions are problematic and you can resolve this with

```
sudo chown -R `whoami`:admin /usr/local/bin
```

Then try running the brew link command again.

Alternately `brew link` may give you instructions, or you can use `brew doctor` to get a report on any problems which exist with your Homebrew installation.

When it's set up properly after running `ls -la /usr/local/bin | grep bin/php$` you should see something similar to

```
lrwxr-xr-x 1 YOURUSER admin 29 10 May 21:40 php -> /usr/local/Cellar/php70/7.0.6/bin/php
```

Comment: I have the same error as the person over here, but these steps did not help me. I have tried to change php versions up and down without any result. No clue what to do?

Comment: You can also try to run `composer global update` to update the version of Laravel used by Valet. In Valet 2.0.5 there is a change to the way PHP version detection works and it requires a > 5.2 version of Laravel.

Answer (score 20):

if your PHP version 7.x and valet > 2.0.8 update valet 
`valet stop`

`valet uninstall`

`brew install php`

`composer global require laravel/valet`

then `valet install`

Comment: This is best answer. Worked flawlessly for me as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 19):

I used Homebrew to instal php7.1 , So I ran this command in terminal
`ln -s /usr/local/opt/php71/bin/php /usr/local/bin/php`
and everything is done.

Comment: I tried everything else and this was the only thing that fixed my installation. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I was going to update Laravel Valet from version 1.* to 2 and ran same error like this

`Unable to determine linked PHP`

The solution was to run

`composer global update`

before I ran

`valet install`

Answer (score 2):

This happens when your brew php gets Updated.

If you do `brew install php` this will work but will install php 7.2  by default.

If you want php@7.1 you have to do  `brew install php@7.1` this will install php7.1 and now  when you restart valet `valet restart`  you might get an error. `Unable to determine linked PHP.`

To make this work with php7.1 you have make brew link
`brew link php71`

you may have this error 
`Warning: php@7.1 is keg-only and must be linked with`

to fix this 
`brew link --force  php71`
now valet should work on php7.1

Answer (score 1):

I tried all of the suggestions here—and several from elsewhere—before I hit on the solution.  This applies to PHP 7.2 (no guarantee for other versions).  If you are using the original Larvel Valet, open the file:

`~/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/cli/Valet/Brew.php`

...or, if you're using Valet+

`~/.composer/vendor/weprovide/valet-plus/cli/Valet/Brew.php`

Locate the `supportedPhpVersions` method. In some versions, it will return an array right in the method:

`return ['php72', 'php71', 'php70', 'php56'];`

Change this to:

`return ['7.2', 'php72', 'php71', 'php70', 'php56'];`

In other cases, it'll reference `const SUPPORTED_PHP_VERSIONS`, and the change will be similar.

Save the file, restart valet, and Bob's your uncle!

Comment: Great, it solved the problem. but need to execute the command `valet install`

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem tonight, and here's what I did to get it running:

```
brew unlink php && brew link php
brew services restart --all
composer global update
valet start
```

It would be nice if Valet had some suggestions on what to do when "Unable to determine linked PHP." comes up.