# Getting error "Unable to determine linked PHP" while Laravel Valet install on MAC

Tags: macos, laravel

Take a look at this -

[image]

This question is different than the possible duplicate - [Laravel valet linked php error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37178743/laravel-valet-linked-php-error)

Because this guy has following result -

```
$ which php
/usr/local/Cellar/php70/7.0.6/bin/php
```

While I had

```
$ which php
/usr/local/bin/php
```

And now this because I followed some Stack Overflow answer

```
/usr/local/opt/php71/bin/php
```

The problem seems originated from the laravel valets ability to find PHP at the location which it expects or it is having multiple PHP versions to choose from. I am not sure but this is my guess. And I do not know how to fix this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel valet linked php error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37178743/laravel-valet-linked-php-error)

Comment: sorry the steps in it did not help

Comment: @samo I don't have the solution, but a pro tip for a good question is to avoid screenshot of error message, it's better to type the out the text you get (and if you like only a link to screenshot) the reason is that search engines do not use OCR, hence your question will be less useful for others.

Comment: This question was easy for me to find (and helped me a lot btw, so thank you @samo), the screenshot is supplementary as the error message is already stated, and it's not a duplicate because I already looked at the supposed duplicate (as well as other questions) and they did not help and where slightly different questions.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue today. For me the solution was to run `composer global update` to update my global packages to the latest version of Laravel.

This is required because of this change to the order of the arguments for collection methods in 5.3: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Support/Arr.php#L175 and this change to the way Valet validates the version of PHP installed: https://github.com/laravel/valet/commit/84ade711b61fd79ead98e08b5186704f68b4f993

Comment: This did the trick for me after half an hour stumbling round `brew install` commands.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer [in this post from The Web Tier](https://thewebtier.com/php/fix-unable-to-determine-linked-php-in-brew-php/).

1. `brew link php71` (or whatever PHP version you are running)
2. `brew services restart --all`
3. `composer global update`
4. `valet start`